# Derived class's print isn't called, why?

Tags: c#, code-snippets

I have this code. I dont understand why the derived class's print isnt called. I believe it is because of 'new'. Which I am not sure of its functionality.

```
using System;
class BaseClass
{
  public void Print()
  {
     System.Console.WriteLine("BaseClass");
  }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
  new public void Print()
  {
     System.Console.WriteLine("DerivedClass");
  }
}

class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
     BaseClass b;
     b = new BaseClass();
     b.Print();   

     b = new DerivedClass();
     b.Print();    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `Print` method is not virtual and you explicitly mark it as totally independent from the base class' one with the `new` keyword. Change the method to virtual and override it in the derived class:

```
class BaseClass
{
  public virtual void Print()
  {
     System.Console.WriteLine("BaseClass");
  }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
  public override void Print()
  {
     System.Console.WriteLine("DerivedClass");
  }
}
```

Comment: I see, because in java it would work(all functions are virtual by default). C# is a bit different in that. Thanks Dmitry!

Comment: Btw, in your example, if instead of override I write 'new', it will just hide the print function in the base class, thus it will call the base's print and hide it from the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes because your b is `BaseClass` `Type` and you have not `virtual` function `Print` in it and as you have not you can't `override` it in `DerivedClass` and will be called `BaseClass` `Print()`.

Comment: I see. Thank you!